# Stuck on white underscore on screen + cant acess terminal

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation

I know there are a lot of questions about this, but none of them helped in my case. First of all i none of the commands the access the terminal seem to work (alt+f2 or alt+cntrl+f1 or f3), the screen just stays there irresponsive. I had this response ever since i installed dual booted ubunto

I also tried and reinstalled the ubunto from an mounted usb drive many, from partitioning myself (i allocated 25gb to / and 10gb to home) to wiping out those partitions and trying the default ubunto install, and none of them worked.

In fact, after that windows is now seeing the disk as "not allocated" even though the usb stick clearly recognizes there was an instalation

I'm not sure if it helps but a message similar to this always appear on the screen when booting on ubunto for a few seconds: noveau sec2: unhandled intr 00000010

If it helps this is my computer: Notebook Gamer Lenovo Gaming 3 AMD Ryzen 7-5800H, 8GB RAM, GeForce GTX1650, SSD 256GB

Edit: i just found out that if i inter with ubunto 5.19.0-32 from the advanced options menu instead of my current one 6.2.0-25 ubunto boots normally

Comment: Seems by following some old tutorial to download the ubuntu on my older legacy computer, i acidentally mounted a much older ubunto version on the usb stick. Just used the most recent one now and everythings working fine